# arecord and aplay in Audio injector sound card

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-16.04, audio-recording, python3

I want to create a fifo with arecord and aplay in raspberry pi3. When I send music signal from audio injector at one end it shows properly but disable the music to other end. I am using 
"arecord -f S16_LE -r 44100 -V stereo -c1 -D plughw:2 | aplay -D plughw:2"

Please tell me how to solve it and how to stop that command without using ctrl+c ???

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, in particular I don't understand "disable the music at the other end", but

1) Forwarding audio streams is a lot easier in Pulseaudio (or jack) than ALSA.

2) When using `arecord` in a pipe, don't use the WAV format, because the WAV header has a length entry, which cannot be filled in a pipe. Either use raw (`-t raw`) and specify the correct parameters in `aplay`, or use the SUN audio format (`-t au`).

3) The arecord-aplay pipe will run, until you stop it either with ctrl-c, or until one or both of the processes is killed (using `kill`). No other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the command you have, add a duration variable (-d) in seconds to arecord like so :

```
arecord -f S16_LE -r 44100 -V stereo -c1 -d2 -D plughw:2 | aplay -D plughw:2
```

This command will stop the recording after -d2 or 2 seconds.

If you use the alsamixer command, you can alter the mixer settings. This will allow you to select the input (microphone or line) as well as enable the output hifi (to hear the sound) and also you can enable bypass mode which will route the audio input directly to the output through the analogue system, rather then the CPU. In bypass mode you can still use arecord to capture the signal.